# Google App script: combine multiple scripts into one .gs file so to easily paste into other scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

I have many scripts and they are all sharing about 5 libraries. The problem is to call those libraries recently have taken really long... like about 2 minutes just to load the libraries before the code even executes.

So what I want to do is write some code that takes the functions of libraries a, b, c and combine it into one .gs file. so that I can just paste the code into the new script without having to link the libraries. I have read that this would solve my issues.

Can someone point me to a recipe? Not sure how to approach this. I want to do it in Google app script itself if possible and output a text file so that it is easy to paste.

The problem is I need to copy from 5-10 scripts, each script has 5-10 .gs files. So I would have to manually open each script, then click on each .gs file and copy and paste each. And that's with every change in the code. I need some thing that combines all of those into one text file. So I can copy and paste just once. I just have to make sure the functions have unique names.

Comment: Why not just copy and paste manually?

Comment: You can use the Apps Script API to assemble new projects.  But I'm not going to show you how because it's a fair amount of work and I'm not feeling that generous.

Comment: @Cooper that's cool. Appreciate the tip. It doesn't look like there is a Google App Script native service like for Spreadsheet `SpreadsheetApp` right?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
class CombineScripts:
    def __init__(self):
        self.service = custom.BuildService().build('projects')  # read only

    def main(self):
        source = ''
        for k, v in ids.items():
            source = self.combine_one(source, v)

        print(source)

    def combine_one(self, source, id_):
        r = self.service.projects().getContent(scriptId=id_).execute()
        files = r['files']
        for f in range(1, len(files)):
            one_source = files[f]['source']
            source = source + one_source

        return source

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CombineScripts().main()
```

Use readonly scope

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent

The `project.updateContent` scares me because it erases.